# Calculating an integral using fourier transform.

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

I am trying to show that $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ using the fourier transform of $f(x) = \sin(ax)/\pi x$. I found using symmetry formula and the transform of a rectangular pulse to find that $$\hat{f}(\omega)= 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $|x| < a$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Setting $a$ to $1$ and multiplying my $\pi$ should do the trick for the fourier transform of $\sin(x)/x$. I figure I have to use the energy theorem or parsevals formula but I can't seem to get the correct form of the integral.

Comment: FYI use `\sin(x)` instead of `sin(x)` to display $\sin(x)$ instead of $sin(x)$.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2077660/695196) answer can help you.

Comment: @RobertLee thank you